# arraylist not work as expected

Tags: java, arraylist

i have 2 arraylist

```
 ArrayList<List<Integer>> main = new ArrayList<>();    
 ArrayList<Integer> sub=new ArrayList<>();

    sub.add(1);
    sub.add(2);
    main.add(sub);
    sub.clear();

    sub.add(5);
    sub.add(6);
    sub.add(7);
    main.add(sub);
```

now i expect main to be

```
what i expect main-->[[1,2],[5,6,7]] ;
but really    main-->[[567],[567]];
```

i think sub array share reference ..so how can i make

```
main as [[1,2],[5,6,7]
```

i can't create sub1 ,sub2,...because actually i do this inside huge loop

Comment: Create a new `ArrayList` instead of clearing the one.

Comment: why do u do sub.clear();

Comment: you can create `clone` for the same check out my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were modifying the list and adding it one more time, so that's why [567] appeared twice. I suggest you change code as following:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> main = new ArrayList<>();    
ArrayList<Integer> sub = new ArrayList<>();

sub.add(1);
sub.add(2);
main.add(sub);

sub = new ArrayList<>();
sub.add(5);
sub.add(6);
sub.add(7);
main.add(sub);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to same instance

```
sub.add(1);
sub.add(2);
main.add(sub);
sub.clear(); // you are clearing same instance you added to `main` list
```

you need to create new instance

You need

```
 ArrayList<Integer> sub1 = new ArrayList<>();
 sub1.add(1);
 sub1.add(2);
 main.add(sub1);



 ArrayList<Integer> sub2 = new ArrayList<>();
 sub2.add(10);
 sub2.add(20);
 main.add(sub2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to an ArrayList using the .add function, adds the reference of the same memory address onto the ArrayList.

So in your solution, a reference pointing to what `sub` was pointing to was added in the ArrayList. This reference internally pointed to the same location.

Now when you cleared 'sub', the actual data got cleared and as there was only one copy of the data(with two references pointing to it), it cleared.

Now when you added to `sub` back , it got added to the same memory location which was pointed by both the references. Hence you see its copy in main.

Hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

you can `clone` the same object like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<List<Integer>> main = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();    
        ArrayList<Integer> sub=new ArrayList<Integer>();

           sub.add(1);
           sub.add(2);
           main.add(sub);
           sub=(ArrayList<Integer>) sub.clone();// clone here
           sub.clear(); 

           System.out.println("sub = "+sub);
           System.out.println("main = "+main);

           sub.add(5);
           sub.add(6);
           sub.add(7);
           main.add(sub);

           System.out.println("sub = "+sub);
           System.out.println("main = "+main);


    }
```

output :

```
sub = []
main = [[1, 2]]
sub = [5, 6, 7]
main = [[1, 2], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Integer`'s are already in a collection that is the basis of your "Big Loop":

```
ArrayList<List<Integer> main_list = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<Collection<Integer>> mySubs = xxxx;

for (Collection<Integer> group : mySubs){
  List<Integer> sub = new ArrayList<>(group);
  main_list.add(sub)
}
```

All of the `Collection` classes have constructors that can take other `Collection`'s

If you don't have an existing collection to start with, then you'll just need to use `sub.clone().clear()` or `sub = new ArrayList<>()`